# dequeue custom cells with multiple tableviews in one viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to dequeue multiple tableviews with custom cells in the same view controller I keep getting the error (Value of type 'UITableViewCell?' has no member 'serviceChoiceAmount','serviceChoicePrice','serviceChoiceTitle','serviceChoiceImage') below I have the code for the view controller and one custom cell (same error will appear for others). (I have not input all the code for the other cells, if I have a solution to this error I will do so), should I create an initializer for the cell inside the custom cell class and dequeue using that inside the view controller?

View Controller

```
import UIKit

class CartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {





let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var TOTAL = [Double]()
@IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var totalTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var optionsTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var choosePayment: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet var address: [UITableViewCell]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let Cartcell = defaults.array(forKey: "Cart")
    print(Cartcell as Any)
    print(TOTAL)
    print("ViewDidLoad")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func clearCart(_ sender: Any) {
    //add function to clear total cell
    CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict.removeAll()
    cartTableView.reloadData()
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var section: Int?
    if tableView == self.cartTableView{
        section = 1
    }
    if tableView == self.totalTableView{
        section = 1
    }
    if tableView == self.optionsTableView{
        section = 3
    }
    return section!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var title: String?
    if tableView == self.cartTableView{
        title = ("Order Details")
    }
    if tableView == self.totalTableView{
        title = ("Total")
    }
    if tableView == self.optionsTableView{
        title = ("Payment Option")
        //dropoff address
        //pickup address
    }
    return title!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int?
    if tableView == self.cartTableView{
    count = CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict.count
    }
    if tableView == self.totalTableView{
        count = 1
    }
    if tableView == self.optionsTableView{
        count = 3
    }
    return count!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    if tableView == self.cartTableView{
    let cart = CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceCart") as! CartTableViewCell
    cell.serviceChoiceImage.image = cart.value(forKey: "image") as? UIImage
    cell.serviceChoicePrice.text = cart.value(forKey: "pricing") as? String
    cell.serviceChoiceTitle.text = cart.value(forKey: "titled") as? String
    let quantityInt = cart.value(forKey: "quantity") as? Int
    cell.serviceChoiceAmount.text = quantityInt?.description
    }
    if tableView == self.totalTableView{

    }
    if tableView == self.optionsTableView{

    }
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.cartTableView{
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        print("deleted")

        CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.cartTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        print("cart dictionary delete", CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict)
    }
    }
}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

custom cell: CartTableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceAmount:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoicePrice: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: if a picture of the view is necessary to solve the issue I will post just leave a comment asking to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have declared `cell` to be of type `UITableViewCell?` with this line:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell?
```

So, when you dequeue the cell and assign it to this variable, it assumes that type.  So even though it is really a `CartTableViewCell`, Swift will only let you call methods and access properties that are available to `UITableViewCell`.

Get rid of that declaration and change your `dequeue` line to:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceCart") as! CartTableViewCell
```

`cell` will then be of type `CartTableViewCell` and you'll be able to access its properties.  Since `cell` is no longer optional, change your:

```
return cell!
```

to:

```
return cell
```

You will need to move this `return` into your `if` block, or assign the `cell` to another variable to return at the end of the function.

---

Alternatively, change `cell` to `tableCell` and use it only to return the cell value:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var tableCell: UITableViewCell?
    if tableView == self.cartTableView {
        let cart = CartSingleton1.sharedInstance.orderDict[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServiceCart") as! CartTableViewCell
        cell.serviceChoiceImage.image = cart.value(forKey: "image") as? UIImage
        cell.serviceChoicePrice.text = cart.value(forKey: "pricing") as? String
        cell.serviceChoiceTitle.text = cart.value(forKey: "titled") as? String
        let quantityInt = cart.value(forKey: "quantity") as? Int
        cell.serviceChoiceAmount.text = quantityInt?.description
        tableCell = cell
    }
    if tableView == self.totalTableView {

    }
    if tableView == self.optionsTableView {

    }
    // safely unwrap tableCell and return UITableViewCell() if nothing was assigned
    return tableCell ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```